# nginx + sinatra/fcgi

Tags: nginx, sinatra, fastcgi

i want to deploy a sinatra app in nginx using fcgi.
could you point me to any rackup and nginx examples?

documentation i've found is obsolete and doesn't seem to work
for me
greets

Answer (score 0):

For sinatra apps and nginx try [Phusion passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) forget fcgi :) .

Or you may consult [Sinatra book](http://sinatra-book-contrib.com/#deployment) for other deployment methods.

Comment: who consume less memory? my app is stupid and simple web service, i guess that fcgi could be simpler to deploy and mantain

Comment: regarding memory usage, I don't know :), You may try even using thin for running rack and reverse proxy on nginx.